# Websockets in background task UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to listen for websocket messages in the background task? I have tried to use `ControlChannelTrigger` on Windows 10 and it doesn't seem to work after closing the application (it works when app is running). I noticed that the registered task is not persisted. Whenever I start an application it cannot find it in `BackgroundTaskRegistration` collection. I noticed that when I use `SocketActivityTrigger` then task is persisted but I have no idea if it's possible to use `SocketActivityTrigger` with `MessageWebSocket`. I also tried to use `SocketActivityTrigger` with `StreamSocket` class but also I don't know how to connect to `"wss://"` endpoint.

I was following this example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8

Previously I was using WNS background task but now I want to get rid of my service and listen directly in a background task.

Comment: A background task is finished when the application is closed. You must create a service for that task. A workaround is to avoid the app to close totally, you can cancel the app close and hide the form (remember to let the user restore the app in some way, a tray icon per example)

Comment: @Gusman why is that? Wns Background task isn't finished when app is closed.

Comment: BackgroundTask uses a background thread, background threads are finished when main thread is finished. You can try with a Thread instead of a BackgroundTask, but belive me, it will be a pain in the ass as it will let the application stuck and no way to recover it.

Comment: @Gusman are we talking about the same BackgroundTask? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: Dude, I give you permission to call me idiot... I confused BackgroundTask with BackgroundWorker...

Comment: I asked almost the exact same question a while back, but Windows people either don't know themselves or it's impossible with the current API. I think the latter is more likely than the former. Also `StreamSocket` won't work with Websocket servers. But you can use the Windows UWP API in a .NET application to create a `StreamSocketListener` and go from there.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken isn't it ridiculous? This is a very common scenario, really the only way is to use WNS?

Comment: @WesleyVrancken (couldn't edit). I tried StreamSocketListener but I have no idea how to connect to websocket server i.e "wss://url"

Answer (score 0):

Would comment if I could:

Not super familiar with Out of Process background tasks but have a look at some of the [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask/cs).

Under `Tasks/` are their examples of how to implement a background task, and under `BackgroundTask` is the sample UI based application. Seems that you can register for events and use those to communicate between the two.

Comment: Thanks but I know how how to implement a background task. It's a specific background task that can listen to websockets when the app is closed.